# Extract Specific Icons from other Themes

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, icons, themes

I'd like to extract few folder icons; etc. (like Downloads, Desktop, Videos etc.) folder icons from a theme I installed and would like to use those extracted icons with the default "Radiance" theme on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Can you please help me :

a) How can I extract these specific folder icons, that I need (for Desktop, Downloads etc.) from the theme.

b) After extraction, how can I club it together with the system default "Radiance" theme in such a manner that, rest everything else remains same, but those specific folders icons that I changed reflects the changes.

Please help ! Thanks for your time and patience. Thankq !

Also if someone can reflect their two cent on this additional query it will be great: Why does the icon files look visually appeasing in the Ambiance GTK theme and not in the Radiance theme. I am talking about the "Ubuntu Top Panel Bar" where the indicators -icons reside. The icons looks great in the Radiance theme but under some icon packs, they look better in the Ambiance theme. ? Any clue ?

Thanks !

[What happens when I install the custom icon pack under the Radiance GTK theme !!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuZCS.png)

[The custom icon theme behaves correctly for the Ubuntu TOP Panel under Ambiance GTK theme. But not for the Radiance?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM4Dg.png)

Any clues/ answers ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out everything. Themes are made according to various categories, of which some are

a) Dark themes: They work great with Ambiance GTK theme.

b) Light themes: They work great with Radiance GTK theme.

Regarding the two themes unite to make a single custom theme, i figured that. The icons are placed at /usr/share/icons  and then find which theme you would like to have. Radiance has Ubuntu-mono-light and Ambiance has Ubuntu-mono-dark. The icons I was looking for were in the status/22 directory. I just copied those icons to the status directory of my downloaded theme and made the custom theme.

Hope this helps everyone of you. Feel free to ask me, if you would like to know more. Thanks ~